# Trajectory Properties

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the time of flight, range, and maximum height of the following two-dimensional trajectories, assuming no forces other than gravity.  The initial position is <0,0>.  The initial speed is 150 m/s and the launch angle is 30 degrees.  I understand how to find the time of flight and was able to get 15.3 seconds, but I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: The time which trajectory reach to height position is $t=\dfrac{v_0\sin\theta}{g}$, because $v_y=0$.